# Need Help Installing Google Play Services in my game

Tags: android

I made this game using libGDX. I already uploaded the game to the play store.

Now I am having trouble installing Google play services to it.

-I followed the instructions and tried running the final .apk file, but after adding all, the Game says Game Unfortunately Stopped working.

Would anybody be able to help me? I dont know what is the problem thats causing the game to not run. There are no errors as well.

Here is my MainActivity File:

```
public abstract class MainActivity extends AndroidApplication
        implements
            GameHelperListener,
            ActionResolver {
    private GameHelper gameHelper;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        cfg.useGL20 = false;

        initialize(new ZBGame(), cfg);
        // initialize(new TutorialLibgdxGameservices(this), false);
        gameHelper.setup(this);

        // AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        // cfg.useGL20 = false;

        // initialize(new ZBGame(), cfg);
    }

    public MainActivity() {
        gameHelper = new GameHelper(this);
        gameHelper.enableDebugLog(true, "GPGS");
    }

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        gameHelper.onStart(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        gameHelper.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int request, int response, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(request, response, data);
        gameHelper.onActivityResult(request, response, data);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getSignedInGPGS() {
        return gameHelper.isSignedIn();
    }

    @Override
    public void loginGPGS() {
        try {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    gameHelper.beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
                }
            });
        } catch (final Exception ex) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void submitScoreGPGS(int score) {
        gameHelper.getGamesClient().submitScore("CgkI_v3s4-UREAIQAQ", score);
    }

    @Override
    public void getLeaderboardGPGS() {
        startActivityForResult(
                gameHelper.getGamesClient().getLeaderboardIntent("CgkI_v3s4-UREAIQAQ"), 100);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSignInFailed() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSignInSucceeded() {
    }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the logcat error here..

Comment: Hi Naveen, it doesnt show me any error. It runs, but the game crashes

Comment: I have added my MainActivity file if that helps